# Supabase Magic Link not working in Next.js 14

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase, supabase-js

Magic link works when sent from Supabase dashboard, but not when sent from Next.js. The return url includes `code` in the `searchParams` instead of the intended `token`.

#### Code

```
// middleware.ts

import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { updateSession } from './supabase/middleware'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return await updateSession(request)
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)',
  ],
}
```

```
// supabase/middleware.ts

import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function updateSession(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: request.headers,
    },
  })

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return request.cookies.get(name)?.value
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          })
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          })
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value,
            ...options,
          })
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          request.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: '',
            ...options,
          })
          response = NextResponse.next({
            request: {
              headers: request.headers,
            },
          })
          response.cookies.set({
            name,
            value: '',
            ...options,
          })
        },
      },
    },
  )

  await supabase.auth.getUser()

  return response
}
```

```
// supabase/server.ts

import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export function createClient() {
  const cookieStore = cookies()

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return cookieStore.get(name)?.value
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options })
          } catch (error) {
            // The `set` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value: '', ...options })
          } catch (error) {
            // The `delete` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
      },
    },
  )
}
```

```
// lib/supabase.ts

'use server'

import { createClient } from '@/supabase/server'

export async function signIn(data: FormData) {
  const supabase = createClient()

  const email = data.get('Username') as string

  if (!email) throw new Error('No email provided.')

  try {
    await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
      email,
      options: {
        shouldCreateUser: false,
        emailRedirectTo: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/account`,
      },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`${error}`)
  }
}
```

```
// app/log-in/page.tsx

import { signIn } from '@/lib/supabase'

export default function LogIn() {
  return (
    <main>
      <section>
        <form action={signIn}>
          <input type='email' name='Username' />

          <button type='submit'>Log In</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Magic Link Email Template

```
<a href="{{ .ConfirmationURL }}">Log In</a>
```

I've followed every tutorial and documentation on this, but no one ever mentions anything about `{url}?code={code}`. I don't even get that when I use the "Send Magic Link" button in the Supabase dashboard.

Comment: The `code` query parameter is used for PKCE flow, and is the way to do server side auth. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/oauth-with-pkce-flow-for-ssr You can check out the example here to learn how to handle it. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-supabase/app/auth/callback/route.ts